# Writing to serial port but only receiving first character?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm reading data in from a machine to windows 7. Using python, I read the serial port, process the data then write the data to a different serial port. Using com0com null modem emulator, the data is sent to another program. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600)
ser2 = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600)
value_one = None

while (True):
    # Check if incoming bytes are waiting to be read from the serial input
    # buffer.
    # NB: for PySerial v3.0 or later, use property `in_waiting` instead of
    # function `inWaiting()` below!
    if (ser.in_waiting > 16):
        # read the bytes and convert from binary array to ASCII
        data_str = ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('ascii')
        if (value_one == None):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(data_str)
            value_one_parse = data_str[7:9]
            print(value_one_parse)
            value_one = float(value_one_parse)
            print(value_one)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(data_str)
            value_two_parse = data_str[7:9]
            print(value_two_parse)
            value_two = float(value_two_parse)
            print(value_two)
            avg = ((value_one + value_two)/2)
            print(avg)
            avgprep = str(avg) + '\r\n'
            print(avgprep)
            ser2.write(avgprep.encode('utf-8'))
            value_one = None
            value_two = None

    time.sleep(0.01)
```

So if avgprep = 71.1, why am I only receiving the first digit 7 to the program?

Comment: Instead of lots of print stmts, consider using logging.

Comment: When you say `avgprep=71.1` do you mean the `print(avgprep)` line of code prints `'71.1'`? If so, it sounds like you're trying to debug why `ser2.write(b'71.1')` appears to only be sending `'7'`?

Comment: Did you try to check the operation with a program that simply displays the received data regardless of the number of bytes before performing complicated processing? If you can confirm that, think about what is the difference between it and the current program.

Comment: Yes print(avgprep) displays 71.1. It is just only sending 1 character or I'm only receiving 1 character. Just not sure what is happening to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I changed ser.in_waiting > 16 to ser.in_waiting > 0 and put a time.sleep(5) after that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).